# appended elements not picked up in POST data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an order page with the following fields:

```
quantity, id, name, language, publisher
```

There are initially 10 fields created on my php page, with this code:

```
<form action="new_order.php" method="POST">

        <fieldset>
          <div id="inputRows"> 
            <div class="controls controls-row">
              <label class="span1">Qty</label>
              <label class="span1">ID</label>
              <label class="span5">Literature</label>
              <label class="span2">Language</label>
              <label class="span2">Publisher</label>
            </div>

            <?php 
            $i = 0;
            //make 10 initial order forms
            for($i; $i <10; $i++) {
              echo "<div class=\"controls controls-row\">\r\n";
              echo "<input class=\"span1\" type=\"text\" id=\"quantity\" name=\"order[{$i}][quantity]\">\r\n";
              echo "<input class=\"span1\" type=\"text\" id=\"id\" name=\"order[{$i}][id]\">\r\n";
              echo "<input class=\"span5\" type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"order[{$i}][name]\">\r\n";

              echo "<select class=\"span2\" type=\"text\" id=\"language\" name=\"order[{$i}][language]\">\r\n";
              foreach($lang as $k=>$v) {
                echo "<option value=\"{$k}\">" . $v . "</option>\r\n";
              }
              echo "</select>\r\n";

              echo "<input class=\"span2\" type=\"text\" id=\"publisher\" name=\"order[{$i}][publisher]\">\r\n";
              echo "</div>\r\n";
              echo "\r\n";
            }
            ?>
          </div>
            <input type="button" id="addline" value="Add Another Line" >
            <br /><br /><br />
            <hr />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="order">Add Order</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
```

All well and good. The form loads fine. All the options are fine. I checked the source code.

Now, I have a bit of jQuery at the top, which lets me add another field.
I had it setup to insert a whole row with these same fields, but to make it simple, let's just do one text field:

```
$(function() {

  $('#addline').on('click', function() {
    nInput = '<input type="text" name"text1" >';
    $('#inputRows').append(nInput);
  });
});
```

It adds the row just fine. No problem. 
When I submit the page to itself, the original 10 arrays get picked up just fine, but the new field is not passing through.

I was researching Stack and other sites, and something I read somewhere said that this happens because the form has already loaded, and so when you add another input field, it isn't included as part of the form data. Is this what's happening? If so, is there another way to do it?

Does this have to do with the fact that I'm using the .on() function versus the .click() function? Or because it's running at $('document').ready()? After everything has indeed loaded?

EDIT: 
Here is the php script that it submits to:

```
<?php
  require_once("../../includes/initialize.php");

  if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    redirect("login.php");
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit' == 'order']) {
    include("html/neworder.html.php");
  }
```

And here is the print_r($_POST), which is called from the included neworder.html.php file:

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [name] => 
                    [language] => en
                    [publisher] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [name] => 
                    [language] => en
                    [publisher] => 
                )

   //etc... 

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [name] => 
                    [language] => en
                    [publisher] => 
                )

        )

    [submit] => order
)
```

Comment: you cannot have same ID for multiple elements.. that is why it is called ID (it has to be unique for each element)

Comment: To which ID are you referring to bipen? The id="inputRows"?
I changed it to a class, yet still received the same result.

Comment: ^^^^ true that, but more importantly in this case, all your new fields have the same name, `text1`, and as the form will submit all the fields by name=value, using the same name overwrites the previous elements when submitting the form.

Comment: Since I'm passing only one new input field for testing purposes, I named it that. Otherwise I would've used an array. But even adding just one input field doesn't pass through to POST data :(

Comment: It looks like we might not have all the pieces to the puzzle here. Are you dumping the POST variable? `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";` Are you sure that jQuery is adding the line in the appropriate place (ie inside the form tag)?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are reading the POST values?

Comment: Yes, in the code I posted you can see that jQuery is appending to <div id="inputRows">, which is inside the form itself.
I do indeed dump the POST data, using the code you mentioned. I'll post the script and the output for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I thought its the fact that you are using `$_POST['submit' == 'order']` in your php and `$_POST['submit'] == 'order'`

Another facepalm?

Comment: absolutely correct sir. thank you for pointing that out.
i hope there are no more, as i only have two palms :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
$(function() {

  $('#addline').on('click', function() {
    nInput = '<input type="text" name"text1" >';
    $('#inputRows').append(nInput);
  });
});
```

Missing the '=' in name variable of input field.
This is why POST wasn't picking it up.

*facepalm*